# gitlab-ci exits the job after refreshenv after installing choco

Tags: windows, cmd, gitlab, gitlab-ci, chocolatey

When using gitlab-ci with windows, I tried installing `choco`. I ran `refreshenv` after `choco`, it skips the commands after `refreshenv` and exits the job declaring that the job was a success.

my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
before-script:
- >
  @"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
- refreshenv
- choco install jdk8
- refreshenv
```

Comment: Is the immediate refreshenv actually required?  Have you tried without it?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark, choco asks to restart. This is the closest compromise.

Comment: Can you confirm what you mean by `choco asks to restart`.  It might suggest that this is rquired, but have you tried running the command directly?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark, I tried running it without `refreshenv`. [Here](https://lpaste.net/8994540276722696192) are the logs and you can see exactly what it is asking for.

Comment: Okay, so that tells me that Chocolatey is functioning as expected, but that there was an error when trying to install the package.  Have you done what the warning/error message suggests?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark, you mean restart?

Comment: No, I mean lines 48 and 49 of your paste.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark, I haven't tried those. I fixed this in a different way by not installing JDK. Thank you for responding. p.s. I cannot answer this particular question.